# How do I get a JSON object from a webpage

Tags: c#, json

New to C#. I have a URL https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/781509#osu/1642274
with multiple json objects but I want to retrieve only the object with id="json-beatmapset" from this URL. This is my current piece of code:

```
string url = @"https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/781509#osu/1642274";
var code = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
Console.WriteLine(code);
```

And I want to be able to extract information (for example the title) from this one json object using this:

```
    dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

    string title = dobj["title"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(title);
```

where json is the json object, which should print 
`Black Rover (TV Size)`

How do I get the json object from this url?

Comment: I would simply use regex to achieve this. You could use a pattern like `<script id="json-beatmapset".*?>(.*?)<\/script>` to capture what's between the script tags. But make sure you're using the single line flag.

Comment: It seems like the url returns a web page instead of a json response. How about getting the string then using `HtmlAgilityPack` to get the anchor element with `class="beatmapset-header__details-text beatmapset-header__details-text--title"`

Comment: @tmacharia Getting the title was just an example as a result of retrieving the json object, I want to be able to get other information as well.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne I've not used many regex expressions before, how do I implement this into my code?

Comment: @tonyy then I guess `HtmlAgilityPack` could really help in scrapping the html and getting all the info you need then I also realized that when you load the page, it makes a XHR request to get the scores which is returned via json, https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmaps/1642274/scores?type=global&mode=osu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you can use regular expressions to parse string data.

```
var json = Regex.Match(code, "<script id=\"json-beatmapset\".*?>(.*?)<\\/script>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].Value;
dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
string title = dobj["title"].ToString();
Console.WriteLine(title);
```